# Windows 10: не работает поиск в меню Пуск

Tags: windows-10

При открытии меню пуск не работает поиск программ с клавиатуры. При этом поиск файлов из проводника работает.
Windows 10 свежая, установлена с нуля.
Выпуск: Windows 10 Pro
Версия: 1809
Сборка ОС: 17763.737

Искал разные решения в интернете, одно из решений предлагает включить/выключить службу индексирования. Открыл диалог "Компоненты Windows" - такой службы не нашёл. Может быть в этом проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так службы включаются/выключаются в службах, а не в компонентах. Открывайте services.msc

Comment: Попробуй нажать на клавиатуре кнопку винды и потом писать то что хочешь

Comment: Именно это и не работает. На других системах открываю меню и набираю название  программы и она выбирается. Здесь это не работает.